# Why do my GaussianProcessRegressor prediction results converge to 0?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing, rbf-kernel

I am using sklearn GaussianProcessRegressor to predict a time series.
The kernel I use is this: `ExpSineSquared(periodicity = 30)*RBF() + RBF() + RationalQuadratic() + WhiteKernel()`. The independent variables I use are a 2D-array consists of [Date, Hour]. I set `periodicity = 30` because I think 30 days is a period.

I have done normalization on the dependent variable y. I am using the first 70% data in the time series to predict the last 30% data. The result is as below:

[image]

The x-axis is the time difference from the first datapoint (minutes) and then divided by 15 so a full day has 96 points.

The blue line is the real observation and the dash line is the prediction. The prediction results of first several days are OK. But I found that as the date increases, the amplitude become smaller and smaller and finally the prediction results of the model converge to 0. Could anyone explain this to me and how should I fix it to avoid the convergence?

update: I have plotted the 95% confidence interval as the pink region.
[image]

Comment: can you plot it with gp uncertainity bands?

Comment: @rep_ho I have updated the plot of uncentainty bands.

Answer (score 1):

Your results might be (partially) caused by a bad choice of hyperparameters. In particular, the length-scale and variance of all kernels as well as the variance of the white noise have to be better tuned to the data. Also, the period length of the periodic kernel might be a little bit off.
One approach for choosing hyperparameters is to optimize the [marginal likelihood function](http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), e.g., using gradient descent.

In many cases it will also be very easy to tune hyperparameters manually, e.g., the length-scale of the SE kernel $\ell$ determines the [length of 'wiggles' in your function](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/) and the variance $\sigma^2$ determines the distance from the mean.

Answer (score 0):

If a model doesn't know what to predict, then it just predicts the mean of the data. As your predictions go to the future, they are more uncertain; therefore, they are closer to 0. If you plot your image with uncertainty bands, you will see that the uncertainty increase with the time as the average predictions are getting closer to 0